# Disable animated ads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to support websites and leave off adblock, however animated ads are annoying. Is it possible to force ads to not be animated (perhaps by forcing only the first frame on a blacklist of websites to be downloaded) in google chrome?

Basically I'm looking for Adblock that allows the first image of the ad to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Stop Animations plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stop-animations/gemmknjnneiojfjelmgappppbaneikda?hl=en

To disable the animations, you will need to press the escape button.

Comment: My only issue with this is that it will block all animations, not just ads. Is it possible to block only certain domains' animations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation stopper plugin , it will take a screenshot of the page or another type will stop the animation and shows the first frame

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-jam-animation-stopper/bclnijbemellankmoaafepibbboobalb?hl=en

You can't control wich image to be animated